AWS Architecture for Splitting and streaming data to multiple 3rd party Accounts
There are no doubt many ways to skin a cat. But usual one is better than the others.
If I had a stream of data which is captured by a rule and sent to a lambda function for processing. The lambda function transforms the data. After which the data must be:

put into a dynamo db.
separated out into multiple streams and made available to other AWS accounts.

My question relates to the second requirement - how to most effectively achieve this. Let me share my thoughts and then ask 2 questions...
Concept 1:
Save the data into a dynamo with an output stream set up so that all new data goes into a kinesis stream / firehose. Is there a way in which this firehose can be configured to send on to multiple s3 destinations in other accounts, or would it be necessary to create multiple kinesis streams - one per final end point? The lambda here is of the data processing type which is attached to the Kinesis instance.

Concept 2:
I've been reading a bit about SiteWise. It looks like it could be perfect for this, but I've zero experience using it. I've added in a few ideas about keeping an eye on costs - ignore that stuff!

Concept 3:
A variation on concept 1 - Could we use a simple kinesis stream, and use an attached data processing lambda to fan the output to multiple SQS instances which would push data directly into the 3rd party account S3?

Questions:
I only offer these 3 options as a starting point. I'm sure there are infinite possibilities and a more experienced architect could easily identify a better option. Therefore ! -
Q1) What would the 'best' option look like, considering:

flexibility (what if I had 10 destinations, some receiving only 1% of the data and others up to 50%)...
cost (specifically low cost!)

Q2) The aspect where data crosses into another AWS account presents obvious security and auth concerns. How can this be neatly handled with IAM. FWIW, I code in cdk, but to increase the future relevance of my question, prob best to frame answers more generally.
Thanks all.

I'll answer this myself having spent some time on it and arriving at an acceptable outcome.
In a nutshell, the architecture looks like this. Turns out the simplest solution is the best.

The Sitewise solution would have worked out cheaper on paper, but it isn't supported in CDK yet - not even as an alpha or beta construct.
While the CDK support for Firehose isn't great either, at least there is a construct that can be used.
The most complex part of this as the IAM permissions. This can be summarised in the following 2 chunks of code:
    // firehose permissions
    lambdaDataIot.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({    // data firehose streams
      actions: [
            "firehose:DeleteDeliveryStream",
            "firehose:PutRecord",
            "firehose:PutRecordBatch",
            "firehose:UpdateDestination"
      ],
      resources: firehoseCustomerData.map(obj => obj.attrArn), // [firehose[0].attrArn, firehose[1].attrArn, ... ] 
      effect: Effect.ALLOW
    }));

And for the actual Firehose permissions:
    /*  options = 
      {
        roleName: string,
        streamConfig: [
          { 
            name: string, 
            id: number, 
            bucketArn: string, 
            email: string
          }
        ]
      }
  */
  private buildFirehoseRole(options?: any): iam.Role {

    // Create IAM Role for Data Firehose
    const firehoseRole = new iam.Role(this, options.roleName, {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('firehose.amazonaws.com'),
      roleName: options.roleName,
    });
      
    // Array of Resources so it can handle an array of streams
    let policyResourcesBucketArns     = [];
    let policyResourcesLogStreams     = [];
    let policyResourcesKinesisStreams = [];
    let policyResourcesRoles          = [];
    

    for (let index = 0; index < options.streamConfig.length; index++) {
      const streamConfig = options.streamConfig[index];

      // Array of arn & arn/* for s3 permissions
      policyResourcesBucketArns.push(streamConfig.bucketArn);
      policyResourcesBucketArns.push(`${streamConfig.bucketArn}/*`);

      // Array of resources for logging permissions
      policyResourcesLogStreams.push(`arn:aws:logs:::log-group:firehose-${streamConfig.name}:log-stream:firehose-${streamConfig.name}`);

      // Array of resources for kinesis permissions
      policyResourcesKinesisStreams.push(`arn:aws:kinesis:::stream/${streamConfig.name}`);

      // Array of Roles for Policy Statement permissions
      policyResourcesRoles.push(`arn:aws:iam::${streamConfig.id}:role/firehose_role`);
    }



    firehoseRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources: policyResourcesBucketArns,
        actions: [
          "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
      })
    );


    firehoseRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources: policyResourcesLogStreams,
        actions:   ["logs:PutLogEvents"]
      })
    );


    firehoseRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          "kinesis:DescribeStream",
          "kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary",
          "kinesis:GetRecords",
          "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
          "kinesis:ListShards",
          "kinesis:ListStreams",
          "kinesis:SubscribeToShard",
        ],
        resources: policyResourcesKinesisStreams
      })
    );


    firehoseRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: ["sts:AssumeRole"],
        resources: policyResourcesRoles // example for test account "firehose_role"
      })
    );

    return firehoseRole;
  }

